# Get Kerberos ticket from cache

Tags: java, kerberos, jgit

I am trying to use Kerberos authentication while pulling a repo using JGit, but I get the following error:

> null credentials from Ticket Cache
>           [Krb5LoginModule] authentication failed

Here is my login.conf

```
com.sun.security.jgss.krb5.initiate {
              com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule required
                            debug="true"
                  doNotPrompt="true"
              useTicketCache="true"
              principal="abcd"
              refreshKrb5Config="true"
              isInitiator="true";

 };
```

I use a custom JcshConfigSessionFactory with the overriden configure method as follows

```
protected void configure(Host hc, Session session) {
    session.setConfig("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
    session.setConfig("GSSAPIAuthentication", "yes");
    session.setConfig("KbdInteractiveAuthentication", "no");
    session.setConfig("PasswordAuthentication", "no");
    session.setConfig("ChallengeResponseAuthentication", "no");
    session.setConfig("PreferredAuthentications", "gssapi-with-mic");
    session.setConfig("Protocol", "2");
}
```

"klist" says the Credentials cache is API (I am on MacOS Sierra). How can I get past this failure?

Comment: Have you enabled the debug flag for krb5? I am quite certain that this will not work. If macOS holds the TGT in memory, Java won't be able to access it w/o native code. JGSS supports `FILE:` protocol only.

Comment: Yes I have enabled the debug flag. For Windows, I understood from this link https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/jre/api/security/jaas/spec/com/sun/security/auth/module/Krb5LoginModule.html that if the TGT is not found in the file ticket cache, it will use LSA API to get it from memory. I was hoping there was an equivalent in Mac. Can you pls point me to an example using native code?

Comment: Show me the output of `klist` on macOS, it is probably a bundled version of Heimdal, isn't it?

Comment: I do also remember that OpenJDK has support for using native Kerberos on macOS. There is a system property for.

Answer (score 0):

The error means that the file with ticket credentials is empty. Moreover, since you have disabled the password prompt (with `doNotPrompt="true"`), there is no other method for `Krb5LoginModule` to authenticate, and thus it reports failure.

Notice that you did **not** specify the cache file at `login.conf` (with `ticketCache="path_to_file"`). So, to avoid confusion, define it **and** double-check that you have such file and it has credentials (with `klist -c path_to_file`)

In case you do not have a valid cache, you can create a new one with `kinit -c path_to_file`).